# fatal error when connecting to mongodb from php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed mongodb server and  php mongodb driver. 
my php version is 5.6.3
I added php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll (renamed as php_mongo.dll) file to my php extension directory(c:\xampp\php\ext) and added extension =php_mongo.dll in php.ini file.
 when i am trying to connect to mongodb it is showing error like

> **Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\first.php on line 3**

please suggest me...
Thank you

Comment: Did you restart php and apache?

Comment: Yeah,i restarted my web server

Comment: not sure on Windows, but on Linux, command-line (cli) and webserver (apache) has two different php.ini. Path is per example: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. Any chance you have same on Windows and you added your line in one of them only?

Comment: i have two php.ini files(Development and production files) in C:\xampp\php    folder and i added that extension in both the files.

Comment: Do you _have to_ use the deprecated mongo extension instead of the mongodb extension?

Comment: i used   $m = new Mongo()  for connection.. @VolkerK